# Angular: how to build a directive to watch a text field

Tags: angularjs

Hello it's recently when I started using directives in my angular app.

I am building a text search, so what am trying to do is to have a text field and watch it to call the search server whenever user types into the text field.

Here is the directive I've built for this:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives')
    .directive('autoComplete', function($resource, API_URL) {
        var url = API_URL + 'api/search';

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.autoComplete, function(value) {
            if(value === null || value === "" ){
                return;
            }
            $resource(url)
            .get(function(products) {
                // $scope.items = products;
                console.log(products);
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    } // Function link
    return {
        link: link
    };
});
```

This the text field used to write the text for search:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="keyword" auto-complete>
```

The problem is the search endPoint is only called once when I browse to the view even without type anything in the search field also the watcher don't working call isn't made to the search server when I type in the search field.

I tired another way since I'm not familiar with directives yet but I got the same behaviour:

```
$scope.keyword = null;

        $scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.keyword; }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== "" || newVal !== null) {
                    $resource(url)
            .get(function(products) {
                console.log(products);
            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
            } else  {

            return;

            }//else
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to watch 'ngModel' attribute instead attribute 'autoComplete'

Comment: i edited the question in response to your suggestion

Comment: You can use your old directive. Just replace attrs.autoComplete with attrs.ngModel

Comment: Here is example for directive and factory: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4D2IYxZd73EwheJViAb?p=preview. If you want to manipulate with DOM - use directives. If you want to get resources from server - use angular services. For $resource service you can cache your requests.